# Can't give a subset when using randomForest inside a function

Tags: r, runtime-error, random-forest

I'm wanting to create a function that uses within it the randomForest function from the [randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package. This takes the "subset" argument, which is a vector of row numbers of the data frame to use for training. However, if I use this argument when calling the randomForest function in another defined function, I get the error:

```
 Error in eval(substitute(subset), data, env) : 
  object 'tr_subset' not found
```

Here is a reproducible example, where we attempt to train a random forest to classify a response "type" either "A" or "B", based on three numerical predictors:

```
library(randomForest)

# define a random data frame to train with
test.data = data.frame(
   type = rep(NA, times =  500),
   x = runif(500),
   y = runif(500),
   z = runif(500)
)
train.data$type[runif(500) >= 0.5] = "A"
train.data$type[is.na(test.data$type)] = "B"
train.data$type = as.factor(test.data$type)

# define the training range
training.range = sample(500)[1:300]

# formula to use
tr_form = formula(type ~ x + y + z)

# Function that includes the randomForest function
train_rf = function(form, all_data, tr_subset) {
   p = randomForest(
      formula = form,
      data = all_data,
      subset = tr_subset,
      na.action = na.omit
   )

   return(p)
}

# test the new defined function
test_tree = train_rf(form = tr_form, all_data = train.data, tr_subset = training.range)
```

Running this gives the error:

```
 Error in eval(substitute(subset), data, env) : 
  object 'tr_subset' not found
```

If, however, `subset = tr_subset` is removed from the `randomForest` function, and `tr_subset` is removed from the `train_rf` function, this code runs fine, however the whole data set is used for training!

It should be noted that using the `subset` argument in `randomForest` when *not* defined in another function works completely fine, and is the intended method for the function, as described in the vignette linked above.

I know in the mean time I could just define another training set that has just the row numbers required, and train using all of that, but is there a reason why my original code doesn't work please?

Thanks.

EDIT: I conjecture that, as `subset()` is a base R function, R is getting confused and thinking you're wanting to use the base R function rather than defining an argument of the `randomForest` function. I'm not an expert, though, so I may be wrong.